# Как обновить данные в таблице с соединением с другой таблицей? ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть две таблицы, `Person` и `New_Person`. В этих таблицах есть столбцы `Status` и `Pid`.

Необходимо написать запппрос, который в таблице `New_Person` сделает обновление тех столбцов, `Status` которых равен 17, с `Pid` соответствующей записи в таблице Person.

Написал такой запрос:

```
UPDATE New_Person B
SET B.STATUS = C.STATUS
INNER JOIN Person  C
ON B.PID= C.PID
WHERE B.STATUS = 17
```

Но он даёт ошибку:

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: Что мешает? пишите...

Comment: @Akina Я вообше не знаю как это написать, можете хотябы сказать как это делаеться?

Comment: @Akina отредактировал вопрос

Comment: Конечно, не работает... у сервера есть свой собственный синтаксис, и он не будет пользоваться другим, придуманным кем-то ещё.

Comment: **Для очереди проверок на переоткрытие:** вполне нормальный вопрос при переходе с "вольного" синтаксиса других СУБД к более "строгому".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

«Напишите [правильно](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/UPDATE.html) и заработает» - так [думает сервер](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a91a3952a290edcc8c3e91a520043a1c).

В отличае от синтаксиса как в вопросе, доступного, например в MySQL, возможно обновить колонки встроенного представления с соединением таблиц (*inline view*):

```
UPDATE (
    SELECT B.status statusold, C.status statusnew
    FROM New_Person B
    INNER JOIN Person  C ON C.PID = B.PID
    WHERE B.STATUS = 17) SET statusold = statusold
```

---

Из [комментария](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1272050/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5-%d1%81-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d1%81-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%b9-ora-00933-sql-co#comment2239531_1272110) ТС:

> пишет такую ошибку, cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table

Если для связи между таблицами используются не уникальные значения колонок, то обновить записи результата такого соединения нельзя. Таким образом БД предохраняется от потери целостности данных из-за логической ошибки в запросе.

Например, допустим в условии `C.PID = B.PID` первый операнд не уникален и возможны два одинаковых значения. Какие же записи со значением второго операнда надо обновить, относятся они к первому значению `C.PID` или ко второму?

Comment: пишет такую ошибку , **cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table**

Comment: Значит у вас C.PID не уникальный, похоже на ошибку в дизайне структуры БД. А что вы тогда делаете? Добавте [туда индех](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=87a953596d95db3137331e603095e8f9): `alter table  Person  modify (pid unique);`

Comment: да PID не уникальный и он не должен быть уникальным

Comment: Тогда переиминуйте колонку и воспользуйтесь другим ответом. ID, как правило, уникальны. Нельзя  обновлять записи в результате соединения таблиц, если для связи между таблицами используются не уникальные значения колонок, в ошибке об этоми недвузначно и говорится.

Answer (score 1):

Формально

```sql
UPDATE New_Person
SET STATUS = ( SELECT STATUS
               FROM Person  
               WHERE New_Person.PID = Person.PID
                 AND Person.STATUS = 17 )
```

Но с учётом того, что значение для обновления есть значение для отбора, запрос упрощается до

```sql
UPDATE New_Person
SET STATUS = 17
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
               FROM Person  
               WHERE New_Person.PID = Person.PID
                 AND Person.STATUS = 17 )
```